# Unable to traverse the DOM to find related input

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want get the value of next immediate input value by class. Here is my code:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input class='name' value='demo1'/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='age' value='23'/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='name' value='demo2'/>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input class='age' value='24'/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

and JS file

```
$('body').on('blur','.name',function(){
    alert($(this).parent().next('.age').val());
});
```

I want the value of age next to name? What have I missed?
My JSfiddle link is:  http://jsfiddle.net/mvkc95f8/
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.age` input field is within the sibling `td` element, so you need to use `.next()` to get that `td`, then `.find('.age')` to retrieve the `input`. Try this:

```
alert($(this).parent().next().find('.age').val());
```

[**Updated fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/mvkc95f8/2/)